# Comparing Two Columns with Different Two Columns in same sheet and Hightlighting which is not matched

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I am looking out to compare two columns “C and H” with “D and I” and return the specific rows in highlighted which are not matched with those two sets (which I call it as Failed)

Where column C and H contains name of the hotel and D and I contains the address of that particular hotel.

I don’t want those to be matched exactly, but if they both have a slight part of the content, its acceptable.

Example 1:

C1 contains - Hatta Fort Hotel
D1 contains - Hatta Oman Road

H1 column contains - Hatta Fort Hotel Dubai
I1 column contains - Old Dubai Abu Dhabi Road Dubai

In this case, I want to compare C1 and H1 and D1 and I1, and those two sets contains a part of the text, so it’s a Passed (in my words).

Example 2:

C2 contains - Hotel Arcobaleno
D2 contains - Provinciale

H2 contains - Hotel Arcobaleno
I2 contains - Contrada Taureana

In this case, If I compare C2 with H2 it matches, but if I compare D2 with I2 it does not, so I want this whole row to be highlighted with some color.

Is there any formula or macro for the same

Looking forward to hear a positive and helpful response.

Comment: What tool / language are you doing the work in?

Comment: Its purely English... and I am not using any tool other than Excel..

Comment: @user2720569 It sounds like you need to implement a quite complex matching algorithm. There's no built-in function in Excel that would solve your problem. Start by learning the basics of VBA and come back with some code

Comment: @mehow thanks for your time and ur valuable advice, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Select columns C, D, H, and I (by using ctrl) and then apply this conditional format formula:

```
=AND($C1<>"",$D1<>"",$H1<>"",$I1<>"",NOT(AND(SUM(COUNTIF($H1,"*"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($C1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($C1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,255))&"*"))>0,SUM(COUNTIF($I1,"*"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($D1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,255))&"*"))>0)))
```

Example workbook here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz-nM5djZBWYX0EwMk1GN1NjMmc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It really helped, can I have your Email ID please